# Load content in the bottom of the page and position it to the correct place

Tags: jquery

I have the following page flow:

```
<div class="red">
    <div id="a"><!-- 'content-a' should be here --></div>
    <div id="b"><!-- 'content-b' should be here --></div>
    <div id="c"><!-- 'content-c' should be here --></div>
</div>

<div class="gray">
    <div id="content-a">This is the content a</div>
    <div id="content-b">This is the content b</div>
    <div id="content-c">This is the content c</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rwsu443L/

I would like to show the **content-a** inside the **a** div, the **content-b** inside the **b** div and the **content-c** inside the **c** div. It is a swap from a place to another. How can I do this with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.red div').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).append($('#content-' + id));
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.gray {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">
    <div id="a"><!-- 'content-a' should be here --></div>
    <div id="b"><!-- 'content-b' should be here --></div>
    <div id="c"><!-- 'content-c' should be here --></div>
</div>

<div class="gray">
    <div id="content-a">This is the content a</div>
    <div id="content-b">This is the content b</div>
    <div id="content-c">This is the content c</div>
    <div>This will not be swapped</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the div hierarchy? My real case is: http://jsfiddle.net/ywc7v2d4/ Thanks.

Comment: @Khrys, where do you want the divs to go? Inside which elements exactly?

Comment: in the fiddle above I just put one example. The id="indicador-progressodefault" should be inside of id="progressodefault". I will adjust the others to have the same structure using the code you did. So insted of '.red div' i am trying with '.panel .panel-heading .panel-subtitle .row div'